# iPhone: Localizing app icon still not supported?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, icons

My app's icon includes some text.
So I want to change language of the text by language or country.

There is a [post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/16/localizing-iphone-app-icon-is-not-supported.html) which says localizing app icon is not supported:

But it was posted in December 2010, one and half years ago from now.

Is it still not possible to change icon of app by language?

Localizing both icon of app on device and icon on App Store are not supported?
Or localizing icon only on App Store is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hasn't changed. I have the impression, given their guidelines not to include banners such as "Free" and "Pro" (in spite of their popularity), that Apple's philosophy is that icons should be symbolic rather than textual, and that the app's name (localizable) is displayed anyway, therefore there should be no need for text in the icon.

I do agree that this is a pity though, as it is indeed valid to expect that icons should be localizable. After all, symbols can often be culture-specific... An extreme case would be a hand signal which could mean a friendly hello in one culture and an very nasty thing in another. Even colours have different connotations in different cultures. An often cited example is the colour of mourning, which is black in the West and white in some Asian cultures.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! I think Apple should reject apps which use text in icon.
Some apps which use brand name or keywords in icon have strong advantage over competitors' apps which don't use any text in icon.
It's not fair.

Answer (score 2):

Your app's icon is a static image, you can't localize it. The only option is to remove the text from your app's icon. Why are you putting text in your app's icon anyway?

Comment: Lot's of applications have text in their icon. I agree with you though: there shouldn't be enough text that a need for localization exists; the only text in the icon should be the app's name, and maybe not even that.

Comment: You can localize other static resources so the appropriate version is loaded based on the device's localization automatically, it would be nice to see that extended to app icons and OS targeted resources as well. It may not always be text, what if your icon includes a stop sign, those are different shapes in different countries. Even if it's just a single character in the icon, you might want to localize it to an Asian character in China. Localization isn't just text, and with how much Apple encourages localization it would be nice to see support for all resources.

Comment: @Tomy thanks. I think icon with no text is cool. But I think using text is a strong way to get customer's attention at App Store and make them understand the purpose of the app and increase the number of downloads.